Will an air barrier help seal a common house/garage wall?
I have a 100+ y/o home in upstate NY. Utilities are in the garage (oil boiler, well pump). There is a heating loop specific to the garage which comes on sub 45F. I haven't had any issue with utilities freezing, but the garage shares an uninsulated wall with the house; improving temperature control in the garage will help overall.
Garage is clapboard sheathing with cedar lap siding. No wrap or other barrier. I'm hesitant to insulate the walls because I do have some moisture issues, but I am wondering if I could install a 2 mil air barrier on the inside of the garage, stapled to the exposed studs for example, to reduce the amount of cold air intrusion.
I'm not unhappy with the cost to heat the house and I haven't had any freezing issues in the last 3 years, but we haven't had a true northern winter in a while. Mostly I'm just curious if an air barrier (not vapor barrier) would be useful in anyway.
As for moisture issues - I often see parts of the sole plate looking damp. I have a low water table and shallow well due to a nearby river, and I'm on the original concrete foundation. So I am just hesitant to put insulation in the cavity and close it up. The house has stood for quite a while getting wet and drying out, so I'm wary to dramatically change that.

Were it my house I'd be insulating with fiberglass or mineral wool batts and installing a vapor barrier. Some notes:

Vapor barrier should be installed on the warm side, so overlaying the framing is a good idea.

2 mil isn't standard. You want 4 mil, or even 6 mil if durability is a concern. 2 mil will not tolerate much contact with objects before tearing.

Don't put vapor barrier against the house (on the common wall), because that should be inside. If you want to block airflow, use something permeable, like house wrap.

If the wall plate tends to be damp you have a rot concern. That should be addressed, but at a minimum don't make it worse. Consider blocking each wall cavity a few inches up with 2x4. Insulate and wrap the wall from that point up. Leave the bottom bit open so it can dry out as needed. The energy lost will be minimal if you seal any gaps with caulk to stop airflow there.



Wow, I can't believe I didn't think about putting blocking in the cavity to allow drying of the plate while still allowing otherwise full insulation! Thank you for that, and for the note regarding the common wall!

Well, it was a fairly oddball suggestion. It's a last resort, really. You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.
